# Trying to fix illko zerotest

Tags: transistors, short-circuit

I was measuring with my zero test and the fuse blew up. I changed it and yet it was not showing any values. So I changed the BUL216 transistor as it seemed shorted (the other one looks alright). Now it is showing values but they are random every time. Any suggestions? Could it be microcontroller?

https://imgur.com/a/TbgFHjF